# Getting error Required android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm getting this error

> Required android.support.v4.app.Fragment
>
> Found in in.ashirvad.dhruv.krust.EventFragment

```
public void displayView(int viewId) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);

    switch (viewId) {
        case R.id.nav_about:
            fragment = new NewsFragment();
            title  = "News";

            break;
        case R.id.nav_events:
            fragment = new EventFragment();
            title = "Events";
            break;

    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    // set the toolbar title
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

}
```

P.S.- in.ashirvad.dhruv.krust is my package name

Comment: check your Import
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

you may import Another one

Answer (score 1):

Please add libraries you've used in this class. My wild guess is you are using the standard Fragment library rather than the v4 one.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the fragment class you have imported in this class is same as the Fragment class in EventFragment class

Android has a built in Fragment class in latest versions of sdk but support library is for older versions or for continuity so those are two different locations.